# How to find the root of g[x_] using If?

Tags: conditional

How can get roots only saved in the list?

*Input*

```
g[x_] := x^2 + x - 6;
g /@ Table[i, {i, -10, 10}]
If[g[x] == 0, i, Nothing]
```

*Output*

{-3,2}

**How can I achieved that kind of output?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xs = Table[i, {i, -10, 10}];
Pick[xs, g /@ xs, 0]
(* {-3, 2} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 g[x_] := x^2 + x - 6;

Table[If[g[i] == 0, i, Nothing], {i, -10, 10}]
```

> {-3, 2}

Or

```
 val = Table[i, {i, -10, 10}];
    Pick[val, Thread[g@val == 0]]
```

> {-3, 2}

Comment: Can you solve this with function `If` Or `Nothing`? Where did I get wrong? Can you point out the mistakes I made here? I would appreciate it if you could do these for me.

Comment: @kile Try `If[g[#]==0,#,Nothing]&/@Table[i,{i,-10,10}]` and try `testx[x_]:=If[g[x]==0,x,Nothing];testx/@Table[i,{i,-10,10}]` Search and study the help system documentation until you can figure these out so you will be able to use these ideas next time.

Comment: `testx[x_]:=If[g[x]==0,x,Nothing];testx/@Table[i,{i,-10,10}]` It failed to give the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to use Solve:

```
sol = Solve[g[x] == 0, x];
x /. sol
{-3, 2}
```

Comment: This is not what I want. Just try each number from -10 to 10.